# Emulator not working/may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am not an expert in programming, I know a reasonable amount from learning on YouTube and forums etc. However, I have been stuck for 4 months now on the same problem.

My emulator stopped working properly and I have tried so many different things the last few months to fix it, the errors I have been getting have changed and I just have no idea what to do. Here are the some of the problems I have been having.

- Emulator was saying it didn't have enough memory
- Emulator would run but not run the app
- I would click on app and it would say it isn't installed
- A red flashing box would appear when I try to run it

And now it is saying there may be doing too much work on its main thread. I have no idea this has been fristrating me for too long. I have tried downloading genymotion and use that to run my apps but I cant get it to run on there either!!

If anyone could help id be grateful! I will post parts of my code to see if you need it. Here are my error messages:

```
12-18 21:37:01.880 1986-1986/com.example.glenmcmurchy.clamcatcher I/Choreographer: Skipped 163 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-18 21:37:16.234 1986-1993/com.example.glenmcmurchy.clamcatcher W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.598ms
12-18 21:38:24.801 1986-1993/com.example.glenmcmurchy.clamcatcher W/art: Suspending all threads took: 27.638ms
12-18 21:38:25.298 1986-1993/com.example.glenmcmurchy.clamcatcher W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.039ms
12-18 21:38:37.275 1986-1993/com.example.glenmcmurchy.clamcatcher W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.913ms
```

Comment: can you post the code for your app

Comment: could you please add a bit more about your developing environment: OS, Ide, AVD Emulator settings